# Транзакции и блокировки SQL Server

Tags: sql

Помогите, пожалуйста. Я битый час не могу сдать тест на ИНТУИТе. Выполняется определенная транзакция... как понять? Какие действия система выполнит, а какие заблокирует. Выполняются две транзакции двух пользователей.

Comment: Ну вы хоть покажите, что за транзакции.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не раскрытый, если ответ вас не удовлетворит - раскройте вопрос.

Выполнятся те транзакции которые будут подтверждены, т.е. те у которых будет вызван **COMMIT**

Comment: Спасибо, ответы больше не требуются.